# width different from 100% for div container

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I have a simple WebGL code which displays a 3D graph. It works well but I would like to set a value for the width different from 100%; i.e I would like to put the webGL animation in a small box.

Below my code; I tried to put the WebGL into a 500px box with CSS "height" and "width" but it doesn't work : the animation still takes 100% of width :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - trackball controls</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
body {
    color: #000;
    font-family:Monospace;
    font-size:13px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight: bold;

    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <center><div id="container"></div></center>
        <script src="three.js/build/three.min.js"></script>

        <script src="three.js/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>

        <script src="three.js/examples/js/Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="three.js/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

        <script>

if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

var container, stats;

var camera, controls, scene, renderer;

var cross;

init();
animate();

function init() {
...
}

function onWindowResize() {
...
}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    controls.update();

    // For displaying
    render();

}

function render() {

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    stats.update();

}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How to circumvent this issue ?

Thanks

**UPDATE 1 :**

Ok sorry for the class-id confusion.

Concerning the div container, I am using `appenChild` in `WebGL` code to add a `renderer domElement`.

With the following code :

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - trackball controls</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
body {
    color: #000;
    font-family:Monospace;
    font-size:13px;
    text-align:center;
    font-weight: bold;

    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;               
}

#container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script src="three.js/build/three.min.js"></script>

        <script src="three.js/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js"></script>

        <script src="three.js/examples/js/Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="three.js/examples/js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

        <script>

if ( ! Detector.webgl ) Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();

...

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't get a centered box with WebGL animation. The WebGL window is shifted on the right like this (width is set to 300 px) but it is not centered like I would.

[image]

PS: margin-left:auto and margin-right:auto don't seem to work for centering.

Thanks.

Comment: `init` and `onWindowResize` are the most relevant functions for the size of the canvas. Please supply those.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your html.

1. your container is defined in your css as a class, you have it in your html as an id
2. you have nothing in the div container
3. `<center></center>` is deprecated Use `margin-left:auto; margin:right:auto;` in your css.

Give that another go and see how you get on

Comment: your scripts should be in the head section of your html aswell.

Comment: Actually, as of HTML5, <center> is obsolete and should not be used at all: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete

Answer (score 1):

1)

The canvas is still 100% of the page width because you probably have that set up in your `onWindowResize` function. In order for your canvas to be a certain size, you need to tell three.js that, not CSS.

To highlight, these couple lines are dependent on width and height:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, width / height, 1, 10000);
renderer.setSize(width, height);
```

2)

You want to set `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto` to the canvas if your container is truly a "container." Also, since canvas' display is by default `inline`, you need to use `display: block`.

---

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/60uzdyss/